# Como criar uma layout dinâmico de sistema de equações no android

Tags: java, android, matriz, layout, tablelayout

Estou criando um aplicativo para Android que resolve sistemas de equações lineares em que o usuário define o número de equações, e gera um sistema de Equações, onde o usuário precisa definir apenas as constantes, como esse exemplo: 
**1:** [image: Imagem]

**2:** [image: Imagem2] 
ou 
**3:** [image: Imagem3]
E implementar um botão que recupere o o que foi digitado.

Eu tentei usar a Biblioteca `implementation 'com.github.frhnfrq:MathView:1.1'`
https://github.com/frhnfrq/MathView e a TableLayout

Android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText ordemt;
private int ordem;
private TableLayout tabela;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ordemt = findViewById(R.id.ordemid);
    tabela = findViewById(R.id.tabelaid);


}


public void Gerar(View view) {

    ordem = Integer.parseInt(ordemt.getText().toString());
    tabela.removeAllViews();


    for (int i = 0; i < ordem; i++) {

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);

        int contador = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < ordem; j++) {

            if (j % 2 == 0) {
                EditText et = new EditText(this);
                tr.addView(et);

            } else {
                MathView mv = new MathView(getApplicationContext());

                mv.setText("$ x_" + contador + " + $");
                mv.setTextSize(20);
              mv.setPixelScaleType(MathView.Scale.SCALE_DP);
                tr.addView(mv);
                contador++;
            }

        }

        tabela.addView(tr);
    }


}

public void Recuperar(View view) {

}
//Como pegar valores dos EditText gerados dinamicamente no código java 

}
```

To com duvida como pego valores de EditText criado Dinamicamente, como colocar bordas e melhorar o layout  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcjtj.jpg em que ficou muito espaçado
//

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
              LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
     mv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Esse trecho de código não funcionou em Objeto MathView

Comment: As suas questões nada têm a ver com essa aplicação em particular. Deverá fazê-las de forma separada e focada. Todo esse código só provoca ruído. Uma das suas dúvidas é respondida pela duplicata indicada.

Comment: Obrigado, O código era mais para dar uma introdução do que eu estou tentando desenvolver, onde eu não sei de alguma biblioteca que existe para tal fim ou implementar os métodos, a solução que você sinalizou não esta funcionando em MathView, editei a pergunta como implementei